# WPF Multi User Authentication in a single instance

Tags: wpf, authentication, binding, properties

I want to make sure that the following procedure is a good one since I lack experience with WPF applications. I have done some research but did not see any that meet my requirements, especially with the multi-users at a single station.

**Problem:** I have an application that needs to switch users with out closing. What is the best option for accomplishing this?

**The Stage:** I am using a MongoDb database, C# WPF, Custom Authentication. It is a single screen with other windows for Administrative tasks.

The authentication is has two options.  First is a normal username and salted password following industry practices. The second I mentioned is a short log in code that is stored the same as a password (IE a username and password in one). This because it is a very busy place and a current requirement is for it to time out quickly, say 5 seconds, so others can not enter information under someone else's credentials. Up to 8 people at a time need to be able to quickly log in and add some information. The environment is a high employee theft place.

**My solution:** This includes the above authentication. Once logged in, the information is loaded into an ApplicationState public static object that has binding between properties and some of the objects on the screen, example displaying who is logged in. When a Command is issued it is checked against the permissions loaded into the ApplicationState to verify adequate permissions exist. The timer is on another thread, like here: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/42884/Implementation-of-Auto-Logoff-Based-on-User-Inacti

**Review:** I spent a day researching and designing this solution. I could not find anyone that had the requirements I have. With my lack of experience with WPF and C#, I was not sure of the vocabulary to use in the search and my research. The other option was to rebuild the MasterWindow on every log in, but that seemed to be a bad idea. Is there another way to implement this or will this suffice? I have not completed coding it, but my tests are working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are asking a quite broad question here, with a number of design decisions involved which are not necessarily dependent on one another. It is a little bit hard to give a 'correct' answer here, so just a number of thoughts:

- When using WPF, it really makes sense to dig into the MVVM pattern. You have probably heard of it when doing research on WPF. (If you're using it already, never mind). There's a bit of a learning curve, but it frees you of quite a few design decisions. In your case, having a ViewModel which exposes the user related properties (Username, commands for logging on and of, etc...) allows you to easily handle the account switching without worrying about the view being updated or something like that. WPF binding mechanisms will do that for you. Do some research on MVVM and INotifyPropertyChanged, if you haven't done so already.
- Working with global hooks to track user action seems like a bit of overkill to me. I would consider resetting the timeout on any user action which affects the ViewModel (Add data, remove data, etc.). If this is not sufficient, than before using global OS level hooks, I would work with events on your applications window. You could subscribe to the `MouseMove` event of your window and reset the timeout-timer there. That should do, because as I understand the requirements, there won't be anything happening outside of your application. Global hooks usually involve a lot of `P/Invoke`, which is to be avoided if possible.

Apart from that, you're approach seems reasonable as far as I can tell... Though it is not an exhaustive answer, I hope it gives you some input for the next steps.

Comment: The time line for the project dictates that I don't have time for MVVM, although I have been researching it to convert the project once they are happy.

Comment: I did not think of the MouseMove event, noob. It is broad, but I can not find a similar situation, so I have to think for myself. That is fine but I don't know anywhere near enough to do a confident solution. I am consuming information fast but it is all theory, which usually is not practical lol.

Comment: Never mind, these are the tasks where you learn most ;) If my answer helped, please upvote it. If you consider it to be a solution, please mark it with the checkmark. Thanks ;)